# Gradle - adding incremental behaviour for custom javaexec tasks

Tags: build.gradle

I have a javaexec task in my build.gradle file while processes more than 100 files sequentially. I want to add incremental build behavior to this task.
Please let me know how to implement this incremental feature for custom `JavaExec` task.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the following:

```
class IncrementalReverseTask extends DefaultTask {
    @InputDirectory
    def File inputDir

    @OutputDirectory
    def File outputDir

    @Input
    def inputProperty

    @TaskAction
    void execute(IncrementalTaskInputs inputs) {
        println inputs.incremental ? "CHANGED inputs considered out of date"
                                   : "ALL inputs considered out of date"
        if (!inputs.incremental)
            project.delete(outputDir.listFiles())

        inputs.outOfDate { change ->
            println "Modified: ${change.file.name}"
            def targetFile = new File(outputDir, change.file.name)
            targetFile.text = change.file.text.reverse()
        }

        inputs.removed { change ->
            println "removed: ${change.file.name}"
            def targetFile = new File(outputDir, change.file.name)
            targetFile.delete()
        }
    }
}
```

then create a task like this

```
task incrementalReverse(type: IncrementalReverseTask) {
    inputDir = file('resource/inputs')
    outputDir = file('resource/outputs')
    inputProperty = project.properties['taskInputProperty'] ?: "original"
}
```

The above incremental task checks for changes in files in inputs folder.